# Recycler view: Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, crash, indexoutofboundsexception

I got the following error on Firebase Crashlytics and it occurred randomly.I'm using EndlessRecyclerview

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
> Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionProgressViewHolder{4950d13 position=73 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.EndlessRecyclerView{815d3c9 VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1554 #7f0a0302 app:id/recycler_view}, adapter:com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.EndlessRecyclerView$AdapterWrapper@e489ace, layout:com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.InConsisTencyLinearLayoutManager@d68ddef, context:com.sportstigeratoz.ui.matchDetails.activities.MatchDetailsActivity@e00f70
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition

Has anyone encountered this problem?

What would be the solution?

A workaround that is I already tried to create CustomLinearLayoutManager and override its method onLayoutChildren to catch the exception when it happens but unfortunately app is crashing even after trying this

But, if possible, I would like to understand the problem better (and perhaps fix it at its source)

The bug is not easy to reproduce, but it is fatal when it happens.

The full stack-trace:

```html
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionProgressViewHolder{4950d13 position=73 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.EndlessRecyclerView{815d3c9 VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1554 #7f0a0302 app:id/recycler_view}, adapter:com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.EndlessRecyclerView$AdapterWrapper@e489ace, layout:com.sportstigeratoz.utils.customView.InConsisTencyLinearLayoutManager@d68ddef, context:com.sportstigeratoz.ui.matchDetails.activities.MatchDetailsActivity@e00f70
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5974)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6158)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Comment: Do you use `getAdapterPostion()` somewhere in the ViewHolder?

Comment: No there is no such method in Viewholder

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your dataset being displayed not being the same size as what the RecyclerView expects. It would be nice if you could post some code.

Can you post your getItemCount() method?
`override fun getItemCount(): Int`

Comment: it's simple returning list size     override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

Comment: I think issue is in EndlessRecyclerview

Comment: @PoojaAgarwal when you update mList with new data are you calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the RecyclerView?

Comment: Is EndlessRecyclerView your own code or a library?

Comment: No it's not library it's(EndlessRecyclerview) own custom class

Comment: In pagination i'm adding list into main list like this mList.addAll(mListApiData ?: ArrayList())